# Distributed Computing with Java and Spring, Messaging or RMI?

Tags: java, spring, rmi, messaging

I am working in a firm that is new to java and I am the only java programmer and I need to write about 10 systems within a few months.. The firm has 2 other programmers that know basic java.  Not Spring or anything like that.

The firm has User Data in LDAP, MySQL and on the AS/400. I am trying to think of some easy why to work with the 2 Jr Programmers.  I was thinking about making them using Messaging or RMI call for all the hard to get data.  Let them do the front-ends with Java and Springs and then do calls to messaging or RMI and I do all the backend work..

I would like to hear some of the best approach on this and the best ways.. All of the projects are web applications

Comment: do you need to develop web applications or desktop applications ?

Comment: then you will use http, JSF is an easy framework to learn

Comment: we are usign spring with spring webflow.. http

Comment: yes but I am looking for something to break apart the backend from the front-end

Comment: have you thought about making remote calls via web services?

Comment: I dont understand why http isnt enough to "break apart the backend from the front-end"

Comment: yes,we are thinkign abot messaging, web servers etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to stick with Spring you could check out [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration). It will give you both messaging and RMI capabilities, but also includes many other features to incorporate other integration styles as they arise.

Answer (score 3):

An alternatives to Spring Integration is [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

Here are the other alternatives:

**Messaging:** JMS, AMQP (RabbitMQ), Redis (PubSub), ZeroMQ

**RPC:** JAX-WS (SOAP), JAX-RS (REST), Protobuf, and Thrift

I have not seen Java RMI used in about 7 years....

(The order of the list is somewhat in order starting with Java friendly to less friendly but greater performance/flexibility).

You can also do a quite a bit of messaging/rpc using distributed data datastructures with [**Hazelcast**](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.4/manual/single_html/) and appears to be surprisingly easy to use (albeit I have never used it extensively).

You can also use some of the Message Queues like RabbitMQ for RPC.